# Network analysis - Correlation is positive and significant, but coefficient of simple logistic regression is not significant?

Tags: logistic, graph-theory, networks, social-network

I have an adjacency matrix and another which represents whether the two nodes share an attribute. Consider it like an homophily test. We want to test if the likelihood to form a connect depends on the fact that the two nodes have an attribute in common.
Now, using R and SNA package, I run a correlation and test is significance through a QAP test:

```
g <- array(dim=c(2,nrow(x),nrow(x)))
g[1,,] <- x
g[2,,] <- y
q.12 <- qaptest(g, gcor, reps = 2000, g1=1, g2=2, diag=FALSE)
```

The correlation is 0.7479487, and the p-value is 0

```
QAP Test Results

Estimated p-values:
    p(f(perm) >= f(d)): 0 
    p(f(perm) <= f(d)): 1
```

Then I fit a logit to that data

```
nl <- netlogit(y, x, mode="digraph", diag=FALSE, nullhyp="qap", reps=2000)
```

but its coefficient is not significant. How is that possible?

```
Network Logit Model

Coefficients:
            Estimate  Exp(b)       Pr(<=b) Pr(>=b) Pr(>=|b|)
(intercept) -2.940634 5.283224e-02 0.000   1.000   0.00     
x1          21.506702 2.188981e+09 0.519   0.481   0.97     

Goodness of Fit Statistics:

Null deviance: 17234.41 on 12432 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4617.118 on 12430 degrees of freedom
Chi-Squared test of fit improvement:
     12617.29 on 2 degrees of freedom, p-value 0 
AIC: 4621.118   BIC: 4635.974 
Pseudo-R^2 Measures:
    (Dn-Dr)/(Dn-Dr+dfn): 0.5036986 
    (Dn-Dr)/Dn: 0.7320989
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked on the SNA mailing list, and prof. Carter Butts courteously replied as follows:

> Hi, Raffaele -
>
> The short answer is that no, these situations do not have to give you
>   the same answer.  They are different tests of different quantities
>   against different null hypotheses, and as such do not have to agree.
>
> The longer answer requires looking in more detail at what you are
>   doing (and your data).  In your first case, you are running a
>   bivariate QAP test of the hypothesis that the observed value of the
>   graph correlation between x and y was drawn from the matrix
>   permutation distribution of the graph correlation.
>
> In your second case, you have a (network) logistic regression of y on
>   x and an intercept, and are testing the z-scores for each of those
>   coefficients against a version of the QAP SPP null hypothesis.
>
> These are different things.  In most cases they will give you similar
>   answers, but not always.  In your case switching the test statistic
>   from the z-score to the raw coefficient gives different results, which
>   is a clue to where the discrepancy lies.  So is the large coefficient
>   on x, and the whopping nominal standard error on that coefficient.  If
>   we look at a 2x2 table of x by y values, we see that your data has an
>   entailment: x perfectly implies y.  As a result, you're on the face of
>   the convex hull of the sufficient statistics, and the MLE doesn't
>   exist.  We can confirm that using ergm:
>
> Observed statistic(s) edgecov.x are at their greatest attainable
>   values. Their coefficients will be fixed at +Inf. Starting maximum
>   pseudolikelihood estimation (MPLE): Evaluating the predictor and
>   response matrix. Maximizing the pseudolikelihood. Finished MPLE.
>   Stopping at the initial estimate. Evaluating log-likelihood at the
>   estimate.
>
> MLE Coefficients:
>       edges  edgecov.x     -2.941        Inf
>
> The netlogit function doesn't have ergm's tricks for recognizing
>   convex hull problems, so it cheerily tries to maximize the likelihood
>   along the direction of recession until the numerical optimizer runs
>   out of steam.  But it leaves clues for us, e.g. giving us a
>   coefficient that might as well be infinite on the logit scale, and
>   giving us a huge nominal se (which is why the z-score test isn't
>   significant, BTW).
>
> So we can now see why netlogit is giving surprising results: there's
>   no MLE for this model.  So anything else you get from it is going to
>   be ad hoc.
>
> By contrast we have no such problem with your first analysis, because
>   we're just computing a sample statistic (and its permutation
>   distribution).  There's nothing inherently problematic about having an
>   exact entailment: it just happens to be at the extremes of the
>   possible data from the point of view of the network logit family.
>
> BTW, if you fit a network OLS model, you will see that you get back
>   the results you expect.  That's also an exponential family, but a
>   different one, and your data is not on the convex hull of the
>   statistics for that.  All is hence copacetic.
>
> Hopefully this clears things up.  It's a good reminder that details
>   matter - and that when you get surprising results, it's often a good
>   idea to take a close look at your data.
>
> Hope that helps,
>
> -Carter